# How is JobIntentService related to JobService?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

In case of `Service` and `IntentService` the main differences are `Service` runs on the main thread while `IntentService` is not, and the latter finishes itself when the work is done while we have to call either `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` to stop a `Service`.

Both of these can be simply passed to `startService()`.

What about `JobService` and `JobIntentService`?

Let's take the following code snippet:

```
JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(id, new ComponentName(context, ExampleJobService.class))
    .build();

JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context
    .getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

scheduler.schedule(job);
```

Can `ExampleJobService.class` refer to both a `JobService` and a `JobIntentService`?

Will the behaviour be the same as with `Service` and `IntentService` (apart from the `JobScheduler` may not start the jobs immediately)?

Comment: Actually, JobIntentService would be better if rename to JobedIntendService, one get obscured with JobService at first glance.

Answer (score 12):

`JobIntentService` is essentially a replacement for `IntentService`, offering similar semantics in a way that "plays nice" with Android O's new background execution restrictions.  It is implemented as a scheduled job on O+, but that's abstracted away -- your app doesn't need to care that it's a job.

Never `schedule()` a job directly that you expect to use via the `JobIntentService` support class.  `JobIntentService` uses the `enqueue()` system in the job scheduler, and you cannot mix and match `enqueue()` and `schedule()` for the same job.

Comment: **Alexander Farber**, according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html#onHandleWork%28android.content.Intent%29) `onHandleWork` runs on background thread

Comment: `IntentService` was deprecated, suggesting you use `JobIntentService` . Unfortunately, `JobIntentService` is deprecated too. [What should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696064/android-jobintentservice-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 10):

JobService is used to schedule background work with JobScheduler. The above code snippet for `ExampleJobService.class` can be used to start a JobService.

Where as, a `JobIntentService` can be started using below code:

```
// JobIntentService for background task
Intent i = new Intent(context, ExampleJobIntentService.class);
ExampleJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context,i);
```

The `JobIntentService` is capable to work for both before and after Android Oreo devices.

When running on older than **O**reo versions of the platform, `JobIntentService` will use `Context.startService`.
When running on Android **O** or later, the work will be dispatched as a job via `JobScheduler.enqueue`.

Comment: I know we can pass in time intervals for JoScheduler when running a JobService but how do I do that same thing using JobIntentService?