# Android JobIntentService is deprecated

Tags: android

The [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService) class appears to be deprecated. Yet the Android [documentation for services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) says: "You can use JobIntentService as a replacement for IntentService that is compatible with newer versions of Android."

So what are we supposed to replace JobIntentService with?

Comment: `WorkManager` would be one candidate. It may depend on what the `IntentService`/`JobIntentService` is supposed to do.

Comment: The service is supposed to create a count-down timer that displays an updated notification as the seconds tick by. WorkManager is good for deferrable work, but my time notification cannot be deferred.

Comment: Then `IntentService` and `JobIntentService` were never viable candidates. Use a plain `Service`, one with a foreground notification for your countdown timer.

Comment: Does anyone know what is meant by: "This class has been deprecated in favor of the Android Jetpack Android O or later"? It seems to me to not be proper language and possibly wrong?

Comment: WTH is android team doing? Why even give us IntentService > JobIntentService and now WorkManager if you are going to deprecate one day. Only they know when workmanager is being deprecated too.

Comment: Classic Googlers. `IntentService` worked just fine! Since they forced us to migrate to `JobIntentService` on Oreo, background processes do not work reliably (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111658/jobintentservice-onhandlework-is-not-always-called). And now they even deprecated `JobIntentService`, replaced with `WorkManager` which - suprise surprise - also does not work reliably and probably is gonna be deprecated soon either way. Omfg Google, do you even think before you do something????? Incompenent idiots...Argh.

Comment: @CommonsWare `WorkManager` is not complete replacement for         `JobIntentService`  because some API delivers `Intent` extras in background where its not possible with `WorkManager`

Comment: @androidXP: In a separate comment, you reference the activity recognition APIs. [That seems to use a `PendingIntent` for delivering results](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions). As that documentation indicates, you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` as being the target of that `PendingIntent`. It, in turn, can schedule work using `WorkManager`. If you are encountering problems using techniques like this, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare My point is `WorkManager` is not replaceable when it's comes to API like `activity recognition`  because it deliver an `Intent`.

Comment: @androidXP: And my point is that I think that you are mistaken. If you have concerns in this area, **please ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve]** rather than posting comments.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sure i will ask new question related to this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @CommonsWare pointed out, I had two options for replacing my JobIntentService:

1. Using a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)
2. Using a [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) with a [long-running worker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running)

The Android [documentation on services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) states:

> The WorkManager API offers a flexible way of scheduling tasks, and is
> able to run these jobs as foreground services if needed. In many
> cases, using WorkManager is preferable to using foreground services
> directly.

Since Google seems to be pushing folks towards WorkManager, that's what I decided to use.

Comment: WorkManager seems to be used for persistent work. I don't need persistence but simply a replacement for IntentService. What should I choose?

Comment: @JohnyText how about using `Service` with a new `Thread` inside it to execute background work

Comment: which of these options would be more appropriate (= reliable) for updating home screen widgets (`RemoteViews`) on the background? I have a problem, that my widgets sometimes do not update, because `JobIntentService` does not work reliably, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111658/jobintentservice-onhandlework-is-not-always-called

Comment: `WorkManager` don't have extras like Services/JobIntentService  (Intent). It won't be favorable for API like  activity recognition