# warning: [deprecation] JobIntentService in androidx.core.app has been deprecated

Tags: flutter, flutter-run

I am trying to run

> flutter run

command but it's giving me  `warning: [deprecation] JobIntentService in androidx.core.app has been deprecated`
My flutter version is 1.17.4

Comment: Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696064/android-jobintentservice-is-deprecated) to your question.